# How to calculate molecular distribution of a mixed gas in an isolated gas column?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

Say I have a (long) cylindrical container, thermally isolated (and perpendicular to gravity). It is filled with a mixture of gases, (He and Ar, say, so we don't have to worry about molecular degrees of freedom), and at a temperature where all electrons can be assumed to be in their ground state.

Gravity pulls the heavier atoms down, so the concentration at the bottom of the tube will be different from the concentration at the top.

What is the formula to compute the concentration of the mixed gases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an ideal gas mixture, each gas can be treated separately.  And each gas satisfies the barotropic equation:  $$\frac{dp}{dz}=-\frac{pMg}{RT}$$where p is the partial pressure of the species, z is elevation above the base of the cylinder, M is the molecular weight of the species, g is gravity, R is the ideal gas constant, and T is the temperature.  The barotropic equation is a combination of the force balance in the vertical direction and the ideal gas law.  This equation applies to each gas species in the system.  Once you specify the total pressure at the bottom and the mole fractions at the bottom, you can calculate the partial pressures and mole fractions at any elevation.

Sample calculation:

1 atm at bottom, with 50 mole percent He and Ar.

Partial pressure of He at bottom = 0.5 atm

Partial pressure of Ar at bottom = 0.5 atm

Partial pressure of He at elevation z $= 0.5 \exp{(-\frac{4gz}{RT})}$

Partial pressure of Ar at elevation z $=0.5 \exp{(-\frac{40gz}{RT})}$

Comment: Thank you, your answer is exactly what I was looking for. If you have some little time to spend, could you please give a sample calculation (with two gases of your choice, even if fictional in molecular mass), as I feel unsure about partial pressure and how to deal with it to combine two gases.

Comment: Or give a link, if this follow-up has an answer elsewhere.

Comment: OK.  I've added a sample calculation

Comment: What I'm missing (and what I could probably find out looking at the internet 0.5-1h is how to combine partial pressures to give the respective Mols. If not for me, please add this for future readers that come across.

Comment: The sum of the partial pressures is equal to the total pressure, and the mole fraction of a species is equal to its partial pressure divided by the total pressure.  The molar concentration of a species is equal to its partial pressure divided by RT.

Comment: That's what I was still missing about partial pressure, would up-vote but can do only once. Thank you for a complete understanding.