# Does pressure decay exponentially for a mixture of gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fluid-statics, ideal-gas, atmospheric-science

According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238470/how-to-calculate-molecular-distribution-of-a-mixed-gas-in-an-isolated-gas-column), the partial pressure of a gas decreases exponentially in height, when placed in gravity. For a mixture of gases, the partial pressures of each component follows this law individually. So, when you add all the partial pressures up to get the total pressure, I would expect to get a sum of exponentials, which is not an exponential itself. Does this mean that the total pressure of a mixture of gases does not follow an exponential decay?

Comment: @AslanMonahov Please do not use comments to answer posts - this is very strongly discouraged. Also note that you can gain much more reputation points from posting an answer than a comment.

Comment: Also, in the atmosphere, there is dis;persional/convective mixing all the way down to very fine scales, so, aside from  the effects of chemical reactions, the separation that occurs in an undisturbed column does not occur in the atmosphere.

Comment: Temperature vertical profile would  break a clean exponential even for a pure ideal gas and homogeneous gravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; the sum of exponential functions with different coefficients is not an exponential function but in this case looks approximately like an exponential function, considering that most of the atmosphere consists of oxygen and nitrogen with similar masses.